# Is it possible modify the megamenu cascading dropdown spacing?

Tags: sharepoint-online, javascript, css, html, sharepoint-framework

I'm looking for a way to modify to spacing between the section titles on the megamenu? I'm thinking that this could be done modifying the css scripting, but I'm not that skilled with the web-dev side of the house.

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am guessing you're using a Modern site where changing site design via CSS is not supported by default. However, there are workarounds such as [writing your own custom SPFx extension](https://tahoeninjas.blog/2018/05/08/inject-custom-css-on-sharepoint-modern-pages-using-spfx-extensions/) or [installing already built 3rd party SPFx web parts](https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/tree/master/samples/react-script-editor).

After you set up support for custom CSS, add this to the file:

```
.ms-MegaMenu-gridLayoutItem .ms-Menu-section{
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    margin-top: 40px;
}
```

Change margin to whatever value fits you.